# Error when I run an email sending code from github on my R. Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, sendemail

So, I used this program from https://gist.github.com/johnantoni/8199088
To use for sending emails. I replaced everything with my own info, ie username, password, who it is to. But when I run it I get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ip_sender.py", line 2, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "/home/pi/email.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mime.text`

I don't understand what I'm supposed to do to fix it?
Please help, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Python is trying to import a particular module, but can't find it.  In this particular case, the module is `email.mime.text` which is part of the standard Python distribution.  The problem as reported is that it says it can't find `mime.text` and the reason for this is that you have named your program `email.py` which effectively hides the `email` libraries from Python.  Rename your file to something else and the problem should be resolved.